# NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.myfaces.shared.util.StreamCharBuffer

Tags: class, tomcat, jsf-2, myfaces

I'm deploying a MyFaces app on Tomcat and am getting this error when requesting a page. Both myfaces-api-2.1.9.jar and myfaces-impl.2.1.9.jar are in the WEB-INF/lib folder of my app (my host prevents me from adding them to server/lib), and StreamCharBuffer is in the impl jar. It's hard from the stack trace (shown below) to see what could be causing the error. Would anyone know what the problem might be?

Thanks,
Neil

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.myfaces.shared.util.StreamCharBuffer
        at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlResponseWriterImpl.getInternalBuffer(HtmlResponseWriterImpl.java:983)
        at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlResponseWriterImpl.closeStartTagIfNecessary(HtmlResponseWriterImpl.java:331)
        at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlResponseWriterImpl.close(HtmlResponseWriterImpl.java:893)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2058)
        at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:285)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:116)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:241)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:270)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:269)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:302)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:163)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:283)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:270)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:269)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:302)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
        at com.encounter.security.Filter.doFilter(Filter.java:78)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:270)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:269)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:302)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:864)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1665)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Is that really the complete stacktrace? This exception suggests that the `StreamCharBuffer` failed to initalize due to another underlying cause. Please post the entire stacktrace, the root cause of the whole problem is usually the bottommost one. Most likely it's another `NoClassDefFoundError` or `ClassNotFoundException` on some Apache Commons dependency which is already an answer at its own.

Comment: I kind of expected some more, but that's all there is. Makes sense that it is a missing dependency but StreamCharBuffer only references core java classes:

java.io: EOFException, Externalizable, IOException, ObjectInput, ObjectOutput, Reader, Writer;
java.lang.ref.SoftReference;
java.util: ArrayList, HashMap, HashSet, Iterator, List, Map, Set;

Comment: ... all the dependencies specified on the Apache site are also in WEB-INF/lib

Comment: [You're right](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org$maven2@org.apache.myfaces.shared$myfaces-shared-core@4.0.13@org$apache$myfaces$shared$util$StreamCharBuffer.java). Well, "Could not initialize class" basically means that one of static variables or static blocks threw a runtime exception during initialization which is basically performed by `Class.forName(className)`. This is usually rethrown as `ExceptionInInitializerError`, but that occurs only the *first time* when the class is initialized. Are you absolutely positive that there's really nothing more into the (hidden) logs?

Comment: Stack trace is from the console - one other log file which gets the same as the console:

Comment: ... so nothing more :(. Root level logging is now DEBUG, only hibernate overrides. Still the same.